# Is there a way to setup permissions so that a viewer can only view issues he is monitoring

Tags: mantis

I have been given a requirement to allow our sales team to view all of the issues that we are in the process of investigating/fixing that their customers are experiencing.

1. We've added a custom column that contains a list of all of our customers so that we can filter by customer.
2. We are going to add viewer accounts for everyone on our sales team.
3. On every issue we were going to add the relevant sales guy as a viewer. That way the sales guy will get an email whenever a customer's issue is resolved, moved to feedback, etc.

---

#### Here is the question:

We want the sales guy to be able to log into Mantis and on his "View Issues" page have a filter already setup that displays all of the issues he is monitoring, and only his issues (to avoid confusion). Is that possible?

We don't really care if he can see all of the resolved issues, unassigned issues, recently modified, etc on the "my view" page. This isn't really a security thing, it is a usability thing. I want to be able to send a link to the sales guy and tell him to bookmark it and it will contain a continually updating list of the issues that pertain to him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a workable solution, but it is still a little clunky.

If I send out a URL like this:

```
<SERVER ADDRESS>/print_all_bug_page.php?filter=<XX>
```

Where the XX is the corresponds to the value of "myself" on the monitored by box. For me it is 52, not sure if that will change as I play with the columns.

Therefore the link right now is:

```
<SERVER ADDRESS>print_all_bug_page.php?filter=52
```

What's clunky is: If the user clicks any of the column headings on this page for sorting the query string isn't included in the new URL and all of the issues are then displayed again.